# How can i solve "Captcha required" error in Google Apps API Ver 2 for .NET?

Tags: c#, api, exception, contacts

I am migrating Contacts to Google Apps.

But after migrating around 300 contacts I am getting **"Captcha Required"** Exception
at line :

Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri(UserName));
ContactEntry createdEntry = (ContactEntry)service.Insert(feedUri, ContactEntry[0]);

I am using Ver2 of Google API.
How can i solve this issue ?

**Note : I am not using web application.**

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a rate-limiting "feature" that google uses to avoid excessive bots using their api services. Once you go over some threshold, google begins asking for the captcha, even when using the api. Put some time in between your requests or try more a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

This morning's slashdot included an article about Google's reCaptha being broken. I suppose you could use that.